# UIAlertview in iOS7 is not getting dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

`UIAlertview` in iOS7 is not getting dismissed when it got dismissed in childclass but not in parentclass. Any solution for it?

```
UIAlertView  *alertView=[[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" 
                                                   message:@"Please Select the Start Date"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
[alertView show];
```

Delegate Method:

```
#pragma UIAlertView Delegate
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: alertview automatically dismissed if you doesn't set delegate for it as you have only cancel button.

Comment: use the `–alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` instead of `–alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` in your delegate class.